# AD Block Plus does not block ads

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, adblock

I was using Forefox 32 and at a time I dont know sth happened and my mozilla crashed. after reopening it again I noticed that it had updated itself to 32.0.2 and all my addons are gone. So I saw no way but to install them again. after installing ADB I noticed that it is not blocking any ads! It is like a piece of crap which was not in the past.
So I ask: **What should I do to get it back?**
**Do I need to uninstall and reinstall firefox?** (My last chance in every software issue)

Comment: Try pressing **Ctrl + Shift + F** for the preferences. Click the **Filter subscriptions** tab. You should see at least one subscription with the checkbox ticked. Otherwise click **Add filter subscription...** and choose **EasyList**.

Comment: @James see http://upload7.ir/imgs/2014-09/54232929647204188629.jpg

Comment: If you press Alt then go **Tools->AdBlock Plus** is **Disable everywhere** definitely unticked?

Comment: YES! http://upload7.ir/imgs/2014-09/26871803803569277960.jpg As I said I am having this issue just after the upgrade. as I said my last problem here http://superuser.com/questions/816158/why-are-the-older-add-ons-not-compatible-with-new-versions-of-firefox This problem is new!

Comment: You could try resetting Firefox which is slightly less drastic than reinstalling it: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/reset-firefox-easily-fix-most-problems. It should back up your profile but you will have to reinstall add-ons.

Comment: The `reinstall add-ons` part made my blood pressure go up ....

Comment: Have you tried manually checking for updates to add-ons by clicking the cog icon in the add-ons manager? Adblock Plus is working fine on Firefox 32.0.3 for me so clearly the current version is compatible.